# Angular Material Card responsive flexLayout

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to position an array of cards in such a way that one card is displayed per column on phone, two and three for tab and desktop browser, respectively. I tried: https://angular-u6akh5.stackblitz.io

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
  selector: "cards",
  template: `
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutWrap>
      <mat-card
        fxFlex.lg="33%"
        fxFlex.lt-lg="50%"
        fxFlex.xs="100%"
        *ngFor="let num of nums"
      >
        {{ num }}
      </mat-card>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: ["mat-card { max-width: 360px; }"]
})
export class Cards {
  nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
}
```

Comment: Not sure why stackblitz is not opening..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutWrap>` into `<div fxLayout="row wrap">`.

[fxLayoutWrap has been removed](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/cb0beab46507aa50c513aca8bb6ef632c397035c/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes), and this is the way to write it correctly nowadays. Also, in your example, you forget to install the packages `FlexLayoutModule` - After you do those two things, everything should work as intended

Comment: If you're researching best practices for styling Angular work, then read Modern CSS in Angular: Layouts at https://blog.angular.io/modern-css-in-angular-layouts-4a259dca9127

Answer (score 3):

You can also achieve this with pure CSS grid instead of depending on FlexLayoutModule. You can achieve responsiveness by [combining repeat with minmax](https://dev.to/evanminto/intrinsically-responsive-css-grid-with-minmax-and-min-1n55).

```
.card-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr));
    grid-column-gap: 1rem; // optional
    grid-row-gap: 1rem; // optional
}
```

```
<div class="card-container">
  <mat-card *ngFor="let num of nums">{{num}}</mat-card>
</div>
```

Here's a working, more elaborate example:

https://www.jitblox.com/project/6ieC-YQVdG/responsive-cards